# Where to download Ubuntu 18.04 Beta 1?

Tags: 18.04

Where can I download Ubuntu 18.04 Beta 1 ? Is it the daily build from today ?

Comment: [At the ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/387/builds)

Comment: @sudodus, there is no GNOME release there ?
dobey, that doesn't answer my question if the daily release that was uploaded today is the Beta 1

Comment: For development releases, you're probably going to want the current daily over the beta release anyway, if you're downloading a new ISO. It will have any updates which were published since the a beta ISO spin. And since 17.10 there is no more "Ubuntu GNOME" flavor, as GNOME is now the default environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find the ['Beta 1' iso files at the ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/387/builds).

Ubuntu Gnome is 'merged' into standard Ubuntu in Bionic (to be released as 18.04 LTS).

There is also another reason why a Bionic Beta 1 iso file is missing: That flavour of Ubuntu is not taking part in the beta 1 testing.

But all flavours have [**daily built iso files at the ISO testing tracker**](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds).

And standard Ubuntu Desktop is not taking part in the beta 1 testing. So this (among the daily built iso files) is where to find its iso file (at the correct time interval corresponding to 'Beta 1', after that the daily built iso files are updated with new versions of program packages in the development process).

Comment: I see ubuntu-server is not on that link. What gives? I have used their daily build, but when does it become the "official beta" build?

Comment: The Ubuntu Server team does not participate in the Beta 1 test, so there are no Beta 1 iso files. The best alternative is the daily build, that you have used. It has already progressed beyond Beta 1. I think there will be a Beta 2 iso file, I am not sure, but there are Beta 2 iso files for Ubuntu Server Artful (released as 17.10).

Answer (score 2):

first thing first you need Ubuntu 17.10 to start with i recommend installing your software on it before the upgrade, it still in beta, but it pretty stable shouldn't have too much issues.

> `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

hit answer once installed make sure to reboot your system if doesn't come to reboot by itself in the installation process.